# SSL handshake exception while connecting over https

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

My java application was able to connect to the third party application using https SSL connection when the endpoint URL had IP address in it.
Now, when the **IP address got changed to Hostname**, I am getting **“SSL handshake exception”** .
Apart from this there were no code update or any other changes done.
Only change what was done is that the thiry party is using Hostname in the Endpoint URL , instead of IP address.

Earlier URL: https://10.0.0.1:5368/invoke/Upload.Accept/receiveReply
Present URL: https://service.serviceprovider.com:5368/invoke/Upload.Accept/receiveReply

**Any ideas what is causing this and how to fix it?**

Please let me know if any more details is required.

Below is the stacktrace of the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret
        at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(DHCrypt.java:219)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1056)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at com.etsalat.adapter.sadad.PaymentLoadAdapter.run(PaymentLoadAdapter.java:130)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

     Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TlsPremasterSecret SecretKeyFactory not available
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:122)
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
        at iaik.security.dh.DHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:648)
        at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(DHCrypt.java:217)
```

Comment: You can just change the url and expect it to work as before. SSL certificate is issued for a specific url, if you change the url you have to issue a new certificate for the new url and configure your application to use that certificate.

Comment: I meant you can'T just change...

Comment: @OleksandrShpota None of that explains 'can't generate secret'. If the handshake got as far as `ServerHelloDone` the certificate was accepted.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota : I think since the `ServerHelloDone` was done, it should not be an certificate error. Is there anyway to validate the certificate for a particular URL?

Comment: @siddharthachakraborty you can run `openssl s_client -connect service.serviceprovider.com:5368 -showcerts` and check for "subject" section in the output.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota Thanks for your response. I executed the query and got error in handshaking.Any idea regarding this Error.  `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
139861929391944:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL alert number 40
139861929391944:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:`

Comment: Most likely this means that the certificate on the server does not cover the new url. You have to issue new certificate for the new url and make sure that it is installed on the server (`service.serviceprovider.com`). Once the valid certificate is installed you'll be able to verify it using the command from my previous comment. Once the command works you can configure the java app to use the new url.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota : Thanks for the response. I saw one more difference is that when I executed the query for `openssl s_client -connect service.serviceprovider.com:5368 -showcerts` but in the Subject of the response I got the below response `subject=/C=AU/O=SAMA/OU=SAMA eTrust Center/CN=hostname.serviceprovider.com`. So basically the certificate is issued for **hostname.serviceprovider.com** instead of **service.serviceprovider.com**. Is that the cause of the Issue? If so, We should be getting a new certificate for **service.serviceprovider.com** from the service provider?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but most likely this is the issue. Note you can also issue [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for `*.serviceprovider.com` that will cover both the urls.

By the way previously you said that `openssl s_client -connect service.serviceprovider.com:5368 -showcerts` fails, how did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota : am still getting the same output. By the way am using iaik_jce.jar , if its helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before.

The exception: "SecretKeyFactory not available" happens if the digital signature API you are using is not added to Java SDK your application use.

To add the API to Java SDK:
1. Navigate to the lib-signed folder and then copy API jar file (for example: iaik_jce.jar) to /jre/lib/ext.
2. Navigate to /jre/lib/security and then add the following to java.security
security.provider.10=iaik.security.provider.IAIK
Note: If the number '10' is being used by another entry, use the next available number.

for more information refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E61144_01/English/Install_and_Config/Automatic_Install_and_Config/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?89631.htm